# How to convert PNG image to webp in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to get the images using the image picker plugin and I need to convert those images to webp using Flutter, image picker is completed now I need to convert the images to webp to reduce the image size

```
this is my code to get the image ,also i added allowCompression: true to reduce the size but ,it doesnt convert the image to webp


Future<void> _pickImages() async {
      List<File> resultList = [];
      try {
        FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          allowCompression: true,
          type: FileType.custom,
          allowMultiple: true,
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
        );

        if (result != null) {
          resultList = result.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();
        } else {
          // User canceled the picker
          return;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        return;
      }

      if (!mounted) return;

      // setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
        bool isComply = await CommonMethods.isImageHorizontal(resultList[i]);
        // Check if the image is horizontal
        if (isComply) {
          if (!selectedImages.contains(resultList[i].path)) {
            selectedImages.add(resultList[i].path);
          } else {
            Logger().wtf("File Already Exist");
          }
        } else {
          // Show an error for non-horizontal images
        }
      }
      // });
      setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress 

This can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the images to WebP format, you can use the flutter_image_compress package. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';

Future<Uint8List> _compressImage(File imageFile) async {
  final result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
    imageFile.readAsBytesSync(),
    minHeight: 1080,
    minWidth: 1080,
    quality: 96,
    rotate: 270,
    format: CompressFormat.webp,
  );
  return result;
}
```

Without package to convert the images to Webp format, you can use this:

```
Future<void> _saveWebPImage(Uint8List webPImage, String fileName) async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName.webp';
  final file = File(filePath);
  await file.writeAsBytes(webPImage);
}
```